# Django. How to upload file from memory to flickr?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, flickr

I would like to know, how to upload a file from memory to Flickr. 
I am using the Python Flickr API kit (http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi).
Does the file in memory have a path that can be passed as filename?

**Code**

```
   response = flickr.upload(filename=f.read(), callback=None, **keywords)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError at /image/new/

must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `tempfile` module to write it to disk before uploading it

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as tfile:
    tfile.write(f.read())
    tfile.flush()
    response = flickr.upload(filename=tfile.name,callback=None,**keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but GAE disabled tempfile. Likely I will have to change the implementation to make it work on Google App Engine.

Comment: Looks like there is some semblance of tempfile around... With this work? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/dist/tempfile.py?r=233

Comment: Nope. I  think you'll have to modify the FlickrApi to directly upload a `str` object instead of trying to load it off the file system.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The API author is going to add support for passing the file object directly on version 2. https://bitbucket.org/sybren/flickrapi/issue/28/uploading-a-file-object